# Running a consumer inside a pipe

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

I need to compose a consumer and a pipe so that the output of the consumer would feed the input of the pipe.

I guess this could be solved with a combinator like this:

```
Consumer i m r -> (r -> Producer o m r') -> Pipe i o m r'
```

or this:

```
Consumer i m i' -> Pipe i' o m r -> Pipe i o m r
```

or a lifting function like the following:

```
Consumer i m r -> Pipe i o m r
```

or like this:

```
Consumer i m o -> Pipe i o m r
```

I tried doing `consumer >~ pipe` without a success. So how to approach this?

Comment: Do you intend the consumer to run multiple times?

Comment: No. I don't intend that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something similar to your signature `Consumer i m o -> Pipe i o m r` could be done like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
import Pipes

foo :: Monad m => Consumer' i m o -> Pipe i o m ()
foo consumer = consumer >>= yield
```

I have used the `Consumer'` polymorphic type synonym which, since it is not really closed "downstream", it can be used as a `Pipe` that never actually `yield`s. To make it yield the return value of the consumer, we simply use a monadic bind.

As for your `Consumer i m r -> Pipe i o m r` signature, it's simply the identity using the polymorphic type synonym:

```
iden :: Monad m => Consumer' i m r -> Pipe i o m r
iden consumer = consumer
```

Answer (score 5):

For your first type signature, if your `Consumer` and `Producer` use the polymorphic type synonyms `Consumer'` and `Producer'`, then the combinator you want is `(>>=)`:

```
(>>=) :: Pipe i o m r -> (r -> Pipe i o m r') -> Pipe i o m r'
```

A `Consumer' i m r` will type-check as a `Pipe i o m r`.  Similarly, a `Producer' o m r'` will type-check as a `Pipe i o m r'`.