# Running a monomorphic Consumer inside a Pipe

Tags: haskell, haskell-pipes

The question of [how to run a `Consumer` inside a `Pipe`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24742367/running-a-consumer-inside-a-pipe) has already been asked, but the answer that was offered then requires the `Consumer'` polymorphic type synonym:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
import Pipes

toPipe :: Monad m => Consumer' i m o -> Pipe i o m ()
toPipe consumer = consumer >>= yield
```

Now, the problem I'm having is that in [`Pipes.Vector`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-vector-0.6.1/docs/Pipes-Vector.html), `toVector` uses the monomorphic `Consumer` synonym:

```
toVector :: (PrimMonad m, MVector (Mutable v) e) => Consumer e (ToVector v e m) r
```

So the `toPipe` function from that answer won't work in this case:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
module VectorPipe where

import Control.Monad.Primitive (PrimMonad)
import qualified Data.Vector.Generic as G
import Pipes
import Pipes.Vector

toPipe :: Monad m => Consumer' i m o -> Pipe i o m ()
toPipe consumer = consumer >>= yield

vectorPipe :: (PrimMonad m, G.Vector v a) => Pipe a (v a) m ()
vectorPipe = toPipe (runToVectorP toVector)

{-

VectorPipe.hs:13:35-42: Could not deduce (y' ~ ()) …
    from the context (PrimMonad m, G.Vector v a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 vectorPipe :: (PrimMonad m, G.Vector v a) => Pipe a (v a) m ()
      at /Users/casillas/GitHub/tau-sigma/VectorPipe.hs:12:15-62
      ‘y'’ is a rigid type variable bound by
           a type expected by the context: Proxy () a y' y m (v a)
           at /Users/casillas/GitHub/tau-sigma/VectorPipe.hs:13:14
    Expected type: Proxy () a y' y (ToVector v a m) r0
      Actual type: Consumer a (ToVector v a m) r0
    In the first argument of ‘runToVectorP’, namely ‘toVector’
    In the first argument of ‘toPipe’, namely ‘(runToVectorP toVector)’
VectorPipe.hs:13:35-42: Could not deduce (y ~ X) …
    from the context (PrimMonad m, G.Vector v a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 vectorPipe :: (PrimMonad m, G.Vector v a) => Pipe a (v a) m ()
      at /Users/casillas/GitHub/tau-sigma/VectorPipe.hs:12:15-62
      ‘y’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          a type expected by the context: Proxy () a y' y m (v a)
          at /Users/casillas/GitHub/tau-sigma/VectorPipe.hs:13:14
    Expected type: Proxy () a y' y (ToVector v a m) r0
      Actual type: Consumer a (ToVector v a m) r0
    In the first argument of ‘runToVectorP’, namely ‘toVector’
    In the first argument of ‘toPipe’, namely ‘(runToVectorP toVector)’
Compilation failed.

-}
```

Any suggestions?  Is the signature of `toVector` unnecessarily narrow, perhaps?  (I'm too much of a pipes noob to tell...  **EDIT:** I tried changing the signature in `pipes-vector` to `Consumer'`; the code compiles, but it looks like `vectorPipe` never yields.)

Comment: Could you explain a little your use case for `Pipe a (v a) m ()`? Do you need to group the incoming values into a stream of vectors of a given size, or something like that?

Comment: @danidiaz: Good question! I'm not doing any grouping, in fact, I'm just trying to make a pipe that produces a single vector.  The intent however is to compose that with a pipe that will produce multiple list elements for that vector. Basically: 1. Read a ton of data items into a vector; 2. Run some statistical analyses that require the whole vector at once (for random access); 3. Output a stream of results from that analysis. But maybe what I need is how to make a `Pipe` from a `Consumer` and `Producer` connected the "wrong way around." If there isn't a question to that end I might post one.

Comment: Perhaps you don't really need to do it all in a single pipeline. Compose the `toVector` consumer with a producer that reads the data, run the resulting pipeline and extract the result vector. You can later use the vector in other pipelines, if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I came up with this after playing around for several days:

```
import Control.Monad

import Pipes
import Pipes.Core ((//>), (>\\), closed)


-- | Convert a 'Consumer' into a 'Pipe' that 'yield's the consumer's
-- final result.
fromConsumer :: Monad m => Consumer i m r -> Pipe i r m ()
fromConsumer c = c //> closed >>= yield

example1 :: MonadIO m => m ()
example1 = runEffect $ each "abcde" >-> fromConsumer (example' 3) >-> P.print
  where
    example' :: Monad m => Int -> Consumer a m [a]
    example' n = replicateM n await

-- λ> example1
-- "abc"


-- | Convert a 'Producer' into a 'Pipe' that ignores its upstream
-- and sends the producer's contents downstream.
fromProducer :: Monad m => Producer o m r -> Pipe i o m r
fromProducer p = closed >\\ p

example2 :: MonadIO m => m ()
example2 = runEffect $ P.stdinLn >-> fromProducer (each "abcde") >-> P.print

-- Ignores stdin:
--
-- λ> example2
-- 'a'
-- 'b'
-- 'c'
-- 'd'
-- 'e'
```